# How to normalize the null column?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have object

```
{
  totalPrice : 20,
  totalCost : 15,
  invoice:{ [ { price : 10, name : "microphone" }, { price : 10, name : "speaker" } ] },
  order:  { [ { price : 10, description : "microphone" }, { price : 10, description :"speaker" } ] } 
}
```

I want to create rules and store in database

- rule1 totalPrice > 10
- rule2 totalPrice > totalCost
- rule3 invoice.price > order.price where invoice.name = order.description

the initial data as table will be

| RuleId | WorkFlowFieldId1 | Operator | Value | WorkFlowFieldId2 | Matching |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F1 | More Than | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | F1 | More Than | NULL | F2 | NULL |
| 3 | F3 | More Than | NULL | F4 | F5,F6 |

so I create

**RuleTable**

| RuleId | WorkFlowFieldId1 | Operator | Value | WorkFlowFieldId2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F1 | More Than | 10 | NULL |
| 2 | F1 | More Than | NULL | F2 |
| 3 | F3 | More Than | NULL | F4 |

**MatchConditionTable**

| RuleId | Key1 | Key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | F3 | F4 |

when query it should query all rules for the object

The question is there are fields (Value,WorkFlowFieldId2) that can be NULL for some cases
Is it okay to separate into 2 tables?
like

**ConstantRule**

| RuleId | WorkFlowFieldId1 | Operator | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F1 | More Than | 10 |

**FieldRule**

| RuleId | WorkFlowFieldId1 | Operator | WorkFlowFieldId2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F1 | More Than | F2 |
| 2 | F3 | More Than | F4 |

Comment: What does "Is it okay" mean? According to what? What does your title have to do with that? What exactly is your question? PS Reorganizing designs for subtypes/inheritance/polymorphism has nothing to do with DB normalization. (Why would it?) PS [ask] [Help] [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Please use standard punctuation & spelling. PS There is a table format bug in the post editor where if you don't put a blank line before a table it looks OK in the preview  even though it looks wrong when published.

Comment: I have no clue what your question is, can you explain in other words maybe ?